# M2 altering bootstrap initial parameters

Tags: magento2, cloud, magento-enterprise-2

In index.php, there is a call to instantiate the Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap object with $_SERVER as the initial parameters.

```
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
```

We had a hack in the index.php (based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thagxt/0f605f0a8a95c79302db0d2f04383788)) so that we could use the same URL for multiple stores and show different content based on the cookie settings.

```
$params = $_SERVER;
if (isset($_COOKIE[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreCookieManager::COOKIE_NAME])) {
    $storeCode = $_COOKIE[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreCookieManager::COOKIE_NAME];
}
if (isset($_GET[\Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface::PARAM_NAME])) {
    $storeCode = $_GET[\Magento\Store\Api\StoreResolverInterface::PARAM_NAME];
}
if (isset($storeCode)) {
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_CODE] = $storeCode;
    $params[\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager::PARAM_RUN_TYPE] = 'store';
}
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);
```

The problem is that we're now shifting to the Magento Commerce Cloud servers and the index.php is regenerated on build, so we can't rely on a change to the index.php anymore.

I've tried creating a module which adds a DI preference for my own version of the Bootstrap class (which contains the above code in the create method) instead of the Magento version, but this doesn't appear to be working - I suspect because it might be too early in the process for interceptors to be in play.

Does anyone have any insight into how to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish something similar (although, not on Magento Commerce Cloud) by [creating a plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) for the method:

> Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver::getCurrentStoreId()

In my case, if no store is set (new visitor), I am choosing the store to show based on custom logic with `$this->getStore()`.

```
public function aroundGetCurrentStoreId(\Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver $subject, callable $proceed)
{
    $storeCode = $this->_request->getParam(
        $subject::PARAM_NAME,
        $this->_storeCookieManager->getStoreCodeFromCookie()
    );

    // If store code is not set
    if (!$storeCode) {
        // Try to load store
        if ($id = $this->getStore()->getId()) {
            return $id;
        }
    }

    return $proceed();
}
```

I did run into issues with a `Segmentation fault` PHP error if I tried to set/delete the cookie with the `Magento\Store\Model\StoreCookieManager` model within the plugin.

I'm not entirely sure how Magento Commerce Cloud is setup, but I hope this can help. Please let me know if you would like any more details, and please update the thread if you figure anything else out.